# fork/exec: child exits when trying to redirect stdin/stdout

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to control a shell-like process from my program using fork/exec, using pipes to write commands to the process and read its output. If I create the process without any redirecting, it runs without exiting, as expected - I can see both the parent and the child in the ps output. However, once I add the redirect code in, the child seems to exit immediately (it shows as "defunct" in ps). I'm not sure how to determine why the child process is exiting (I don't see any output from it), so I'm struggling to diagnose the problem.

My code looks something like this:

```
int in[2], out[2];
FILE *in_fp, *out_fp;

pipe(in);
pipe(out);

if (fork()) {
    close(in[0]);
    close(out[1]);
    in_fp = fdopen(in[1], "w");
    out_fp = fdopen(out[0], "r");

    // Here I'll use in_fp and out_fp to communicate with the child.
} else {
    dup2(in[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(out[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(in[0]);
    close(in[1]);
    close(out[0]);
    close(out[1]);

    execlp("child_process", NULL);
}
```

Does anyone know why this might not be working, or suggest how I can get more info about why the child process exits?

edit: So strace reveals the child process is crashing with a SIGSEGV, and looks like it's in Py_SetProgramName - though can't work out why yet (don't have access to the child's symbols).

Comment: re: getting more information, `strace -f` is your friend; `sysdig` doubly so.

Comment: just in case: I think you want `fdopen` not `fopen` in the parent.

Comment: Yes sorry - that's a typo, I have fdopen in the actual code, have corrected this.

Comment: You are closing `out[0]` twice instead of `out[1]`, is that a typo too?

Comment: Yes sorry - I was having clipboard problems with VNC, so I ended up typing it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is in the call to `execlp()`.

Although technically the list of arguments may be empty, it is standard practice to add always at least one argument, that will be `argv[0]` in `main()`, with the actual name used to invoke the program. Likely the python program uses this `arg0` as argument to `Py_SetProgramName()` without checking for `NULL`.

So write instead:

```
execlp("child_process", "child_process", (char*)NULL);
```

Also note that, citing from `man execlp`:

> The list of arguments must be terminated by a null
>          pointer, and, since these are variadic functions, this pointer **must be cast `(char *)NULL`**